# I am not getting the marker for current location when i load the window

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, yii2

```
<?php

namespace ibrarturi\latlngfinder;

use yii\web\View;

/**
 * A widget to find Latitude and Longitude using Google Maps for Yii Framework 2
 * by Ibrar Turi
 *
 * @see https://github.com/ibrarturi/yii2-latlon-finder
 * @author Ibrar Turi <ibrarturi@gmail.com>
 * @since 1.0
 */
class LatLngFinder extends \yii\base\Widget
{
    /**
     * @var string $latAttribute Latitude attribute id
     */
    public $latAttribute    = null;

    /**
     * @var string $lngAttribute Longitude attribute id
     */
    public $lngAttribute    = null;

    /**
     * @var string $zoomAttribute Zomm attribute id
     */
    public $zoomAttribute   = null;

    /**
     * @var string $mapCanvasId Map canvas id
     */
    public $mapCanvasId     = null;

    /**
     * @var integer $mapWidth Width of the map canvas
     */
    public $mapWidth        = null;

    /**
     * @var integer $mapHeight Height of the map canvas
     */
    public $mapHeight       = null;

    /**
     * @var float $defaultLat Default Latitude for the map
     */
    public $defaultLat      = null;

    /**
     * @var float $defaultLng Default Longitude for the map
     */
    public $defaultLng      = null;

    /**
     * @var integer $defaultZoom Default initial Zoom for the map
     */
    public $defaultZoom     = null;

    /**
     * @var bool $enableZoomField If set to boolean true then the zoom value will be assinged to the zoom field
     */
    public $enableZoomField = null;

    /**
     * @var object $model Object model
     */
    public $model = null;


    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->model                = ( isset($this->model) ) ? $this->model : null;

        if ($this->model) 
        {
            $formName = strtolower($this->model->formName());

            $this->latAttribute     = ( isset($this->latAttribute) ) ? $formName.'-'.$this->latAttribute : $formName.'-'.'lat';
            $this->lngAttribute     = ( isset($this->lngAttribute) ) ? $formName.'-'.$this->lngAttribute : $formName.'-'.'lng';
            $this->zoomAttribute    = ( isset($this->zoomAttribute) ) ? $formName.'-'.$this->zoomAttribute : $formName.'-'.'zoom';
        } 
        else 
        {
            $this->latAttribute     = ( isset($this->latAttribute) ) ? $this->latAttribute : 'lat';
            $this->lngAttribute     = ( isset($this->lngAttribute) ) ? $this->lngAttribute : 'lng';
            $this->zoomAttribute    = ( isset($this->zoomAttribute) ) ? $this->zoomAttribute : 'zoom';
        }

        $this->mapCanvasId      = ( isset($this->mapCanvasId) ) ? $this->mapCanvasId : 'map';
        $this->mapWidth         = ( isset($this->mapWidth) ) ? $this->mapWidth : 450;
        $this->mapHeight        = ( isset($this->mapHeight) ) ? $this->mapHeight : 300;
        $this->defaultLat       = ( isset($this->defaultLat) ) ? $this->defaultLat : -34.397;
        $this->defaultLng       = ( isset($this->defaultLng) ) ? $this->defaultLng : 150.644;
        $this->defaultZoom      = ( isset($this->defaultZoom) ) ? $this->defaultZoom : 8;
        $this->enableZoomField  = ( isset($this->enableZoomField) ) ? ( ($this->enableZoomField==true) ? 1 : 0 ) : true;

        $this->registerAssets();

    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $js = <<<SCRIPT

            var map = null;
            var marker = null;
            var markers = [];
            var enalbeZoom = $this->enableZoomField;

            function initMap() {
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: $this->defaultZoom,
                    center: {lat: $this->defaultLat, lng: $this->defaultLng},
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('$this->mapCanvasId'), mapOptions);

                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
                    placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function(e) {
                    var zoom = map.getZoom();
                    if (enalbeZoom) { document.getElementById('$this->zoomAttribute').value = zoom; }
                });
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

            function placeMarker(position, map) {
                    if(marker){
                         marker.setMap(null);
                    }                   

                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: position,
                        draggable: true,
                        map: map
                    });

                    var lat = position.lat();
                    var lng = position.lng();
                    var zoom = map.getZoom();

                    document.getElementById('$this->latAttribute').value = lat;
                    document.getElementById('$this->lngAttribute').value = lng;
                    if (enalbeZoom) { document.getElementById('$this->zoomAttribute').value = zoom; }

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function(e) {
                        var lat = e.latLng.lat();
                        var lng = e.latLng.lng();
                        var zoom = map.getZoom();

                        document.getElementById('$this->latAttribute').value = lat;
                        document.getElementById('$this->lngAttribute').value = lng;
                        if (enalbeZoom) { document.getElementById('$this->zoomAttribute').value = zoom; }
                    });

                    map.panTo(position);
                    /*markers.push(marker);*/
                    marker.setMap(map);

            }


SCRIPT;

        $this->getView()->registerJs($js);

        echo '<div id="' . $this->mapCanvasId . '" style="width:'.$this->mapWidth.'px;height:'.$this->mapHeight.'px; margin-bottom: 20px;"></div>';

    }

    protected function registerAssets()
    {
        $view = $this->getView();
        $view->registerJsFile('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDiP7bkTtT0wDRwh9tqZoYwErHAMc_BgGM', ['position' => View::POS_HEAD]);
    }
}
```

view:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'fpro_lat') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'fpro_lan') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'fpro_field2')->textInput(['readOnly' => true]) ?>

    <?= \ibrarturi\latlngfinder\LatLngFinder::widget([
        'model' => $model,          
        'latAttribute' => 'fpro_lat',        
        'lngAttribute' => 'fpro_lan',        
        'zoomAttribute' => 'fpro_field2',      
        'mapCanvasId' => 'map',
        'mapWidth' => 350,              
        'mapHeight' => 300,             
        'defaultLat' => 13.0915117329,        
        'defaultLng' => 77.4077528715,         
        'defaultZoom' => 20,            
        'enableZoomField' => true,      
    ]); ?>
```

I am using the Yii2 Framework and jQuery to select Latitude and longitude. It's working fine but, when I load the window, the marker is not shown in the default location in the Google Maps that I have given. After clicking on Google Maps I am getting the marker.

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You have placed you placeMarker call only inside the click eevnt listner so the placeMarker function is called only when you click the map ..
if you want see the marker at startup you should invoke the palceMarker function also after the google maps creation

```
        function initMap() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: $this->defaultZoom,
                center: {lat: $this->defaultLat, lng: $this->defaultLng},
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('$this->mapCanvasId'), mapOptions);

            placeMarker({lat: $this->defaultLat, lng: $this->defaultLng}, map);
            ......
```